# Raspbmc only plays one song at a time

Tags: raspbmc, kodi

After installing Raspbmc and queueing up some songs I noticed that only the first track is played then it stops.

Same with trying to just play one album all the way thru: first song, then stops.

Playing videos seems to work just fine.

Running `grep XBMC .xbmc/temp/xbmc.log | head -1` to get the release version installed, this is what I get:

```
13:04:10 T:3037835264  NOTICE: Starting XBMC (12.0-RC2 Git:20121227-0090665), Platform: Linux (Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 (wheezy), 3.6.11 armv6l). Built on Dec 28 2012
```

Couldn't find this question previously asked: did anybody else ran into this problem / find an elegant solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem in the current RC. Just switch to the latest nightly release and this is fixed.

Comment: That solved it, thanks! Any idea when is the next stable release scheduled for?

Comment: No idea. I'm just a user that had the same problem as you :)